# How to start with writing a RESTful service?

Tags: rest, servlets

I am trying to create a RESTful web service that accepts JSON arguments and gives out a JSON response.

What I want is to accept HTTP requests made to my URL endpoint. 
Something like,

> POST /the/endpoint HTTP/1.1 
>   Host: mywebsite.com
>
> {"name":"yourname", "department":"your_department"}

Do a DB read at the backend and give relevant parameters like, say Manager name, salary etc as a JSON object, as the response.

What's the best way to go about it? I was thinking of using Java servlets for this? Is there a better way?

PS - I am just getting started so detailed answers or links to tutorials as to how to implement it would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: what have you searched ? what have you tried ? what did not work for you ? it works both ways here.

Comment: hey, I just want to get started. Since a HTTP endpoint is pretty much generic i wanted to know what's the best way to get started. Servlets seemed to be an answer. Any better choice? that's what i wanted to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can easily do this with Servlets and some Json Libs for Marshalling /unmarshalling the  Json Object to Java Object.

You can make use of Json libs like 
    [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) , 
     [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) etc

But you must know that REST application doesnt end with just handling the request and response , but it needs to take care of other non-functional requirements like

- Authentication
- Authorization
- Security  etc

Building this from a scratch from a Servlet is overkill and waste of time when there are ready made frameworks that these things for you 
My favorite is Spring MVC 3.0

Check their project site for more details

Just to show you how easy to set up one in Spring MVC , check this below tutorial
[Spring 3 REST Tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-rest-hello-world-example/)

Pls rate the post if it helps , Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with Java, I suggest that you take a look at JAX-RS... And since REST is a complex topic, here is a url with tons of informations on it. http://code.google.com/p/implementing-rest/

Answer (score 0):

As a complete beginner, I believe the best way to implement a (nearly) RESTful API without having to read a lot is simply to implement the API just using HTML pages and HTML forms with the back-end processing to handle them.

The rules are:

1. Use `<a>` tags to provide links to related resources. (navigation)
2. Use `<form>` tags to initiate any kind of processing operation on the server. (actions)

You can then make it properly RESTful by using progressive enhancement to add Javascript AJAX requests that perform `PUT`, `PATCH`, and `DELETE` instead of using `POST` for those three (of course, keeping POST for creating resources where the client doesn't know the resultant URI).

You can then click around and test the API in a web browser! Tools like Selenium can automate this.

If you need to provide JSON, this can be added after the API has been designed and tested, although libraries exist to process HTML or XHTML responses too, so JSON isn't necessarily required for machine readability.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using php with symfony try:https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle this lets you create a real REST full servicer very quick.

Answer (score 0):

Vogella made my day very easy when i started Web services  with an super example here with eclipse screen shots ..Have a look [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html).